# Who was the girl in London?

Tags: plot-explanation, the-war-zone

There's only one scene in [*The War Zone*](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0141974/) that is shot in a city, which I assume to be London (as implied by the story.) The girl that the brother and his sister meet there seems to be a prostitute, set up for him by his sister. Yet, she interrupts them when the "prostitute" was just getting started.

Did the sister change her mind, or did I miss something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a few possible explanations for this:

1. Firstly, you could argue that it is because the sister suddenly realises what she is doing is a form of abuse - by putting her brother in a sexual situation which he didn't choose to be in. Given all the events of her life, this sudden realisation is certainly plausible. She did for him what no one ever did for her.
2. Another possible reason I've read at the [IMDB forums](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0141974/board/thread/199577008) is that the director perhaps didn't want to portray all abuse as being cyclical, i.e. that the abused will become abusers.